# How to debug web-socket connection while running tests in Moon?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, sockets

The problem is that:

Autotests **fail** when I run tests **in Moon Chrome**.

But the same tests **pass** when I run them **locally in Chrome**.

I guess this problem is somehow connected with websocket connection between FE & BE. Because all other stuff on the tested page is displayed correctly while both running in Moon & locally.

So can you give me any advice about debugging WS while running tests in Moon?
I mean something that could trace WS connection (status, messages).

Automation is done with webdriver.io